# Changing bytes() (Python 3 string) output back to list of ints

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, integer

I am building a zipping software, and i am having trouble changing back my bytes to ints.
i used the function bytes(), on an list of ints, the function returns a byte, but now when i am trying to decode it i am getting an error.

example:

```
    code = bytes([231, 131])
    code.decode()
```

and than i am getting the next error:

unicodeDecoderError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in postion 0-1: unexpected end of data

I am not understanding the whole bytes thing to good, so be nice.
thank you

Comment: That is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: Why do you *need* the decoding step anyway? `bytes` should work as a sequence of `int`s.

Comment: i need it for the unzip, there is no way to reverse bytes() action?

Comment: If you just mean you want a list of ints again, then `list(code)`. Like millimoose says, a `bytes` object isn't far off *being* a list of ints.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, one can easily convert from a list of integers to the bytes type.

```
>>> code = bytes([231, 131])
>>> code
b'\xe7\x83'
>>> type(code)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Coercing the bytes type to list converts the unicode back to a list of integers:

```
>>> list(code)
[231, 131]
```